# How to make HTTPD list directory of subdomain?

Tags: linux, web, httpd

I have created a subdomain on my website using HTTPD and am wondering how to make it display the list of files in the directory instead of the Apache Test Page. Is there a directive I can add to the virtualhost for it?

Answer (score 1):

Turn on the Indexes option for the subdirectory.  I.e. put

```
<Directory "directory-path">
    Options Indexes
</Directory>
```

into Apache's httpd.conf.

Replace directory-path with the path to the subdirectory.

Comment: Hmm, I tried adding that but it still seems to not be working, are there any other options required?

Comment: Yes, delete the `index.html` file inside httpd root directory.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't have an index.html though, I just make some assorted random empty files to test it (Sorry I didn't specify). Looking in the error_log though I am seeing this: `Directory index forbidden by Options directive`